# Javascript How to add array with another array into a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

So my challenge right now is unable to add array with another array into another new array.

my code:

```
var disabletimerange = { basedonservicetype: "", basedonservicer: "" }
var arr = [{"StartTime":"09:00:00","EndTime":"09:10:00"},{"StartTime":"10:00:00","EndTime":"15:00:00"}]
for (var xx = 0; xx < arr.length; xx++) {
    var bookedStartTime, bookedEndTime
    bookedStartTime = arr[xx].StartTime.slice(0, -3)
    bookedEndTime = arr[xx].EndTime.slice(0, -3)

    if (disabletimerange.basedonservicer === "") {
        var disabletimealreadybookedtiming = "[" + '"' + bookedStartTime + '"' + "," + '"' + bookedEndTime + '"' + "]"
        disabletimerange.basedonservicer = JSON.parse(disabletimealreadybookedtiming)
    } else {
        var disabletimealreadybookedtiming = "[" + '"' + bookedStartTime + '"' + "," + '"' + bookedEndTime + '"' + "]"
        disabletimerange.basedonservicer = "[" + "[" + disabletimerange.basedonservicer + "]" + "," + disabletimealreadybookedtiming + "]"
        disabletimerange.basedonservicer = JSON.parse(disabletimerange.basedonservicer)
}
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 3 --> at the last line it cannot parse.

In short, what i want is basically 2 array stick tgt instead of adding into it

```
var y = ["hi", "123"]
var x = ["yo", "312"]

this
[["hi", "123"], ["yo", "312"]] instead of ["hi", "123", "yo", "312"]
```

and it must be array. not text form

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```js
var y = ["hi", "123"]
var x = ["yo", "312"]

var result = [x, y]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you described

> How to add array with another array into a new array?

- create a new array
- push your arrays into this new array one by one

```js
let x = [1,2];
let y = [3.4];

let z = [];
z.push(x)
z.push(y);

console.log(z);
```